# Assignment in braces vs outside braces in awk

Tags: awk

From [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/145648/merging-columns-from-two-separate-files/145649#145649), I answer with this solution:

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[FNR]=$2;next}{$NF=a[FNR]}1' file2 file1
```

It works as expected.

But the first solution I thought is:

```
$ awk 'FNR==NR{a[FNR]=$2;next}$NF=a[FNR]' file2 file1
A 63 9 6
B 45 3 5
```

It does not work, since when `awk` had not print the first line in `file1`. It make me suprise, and don't know why `awk` skip the first line.

Here is some examples:

```
$ awk 'FNR==NR{next}$1=123' file2 file1 
123 23 8 T
123 63 9 9
123 45 3 J  

$ awk 'FNR==NR{a[FNR]=$2;next} FNR in a' file2 file1
A   23  8   T
A   63  9   9
B   45  3   J
```

You can see, from both examples, `awk` works as expected. First assigning new value to a field of current record affected record value, and `awk` print new value. The second show that `awk` had process all record in `file2`, no record is skipped.

Why `awk` skip the first line in my first solution?

I use `gawk 4.0.1`, and also tested with `mawk 1.3.3`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some research, I found the answer.

First, according to [this](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xcu/awk.html):

```
Expression Patterns

An expression pattern will be evaluated as if it were an expression in a 
Boolean context. If the result is true, the pattern will be considered to 
match, and the associated action (if any) will be executed. If the result is 
false, the action will not be executed.
```

So in my example, `$NF=a[FNR]` will be considered as an expression pattern. As the doc said, the result of assignment is evaluated to `true` or `false`.

In my example, the result of assignment is `0`, which is evaluate to `false` in boolean context, causing the the pattern is considered as not match, no action is executed.

**Note for @Michael Homer**

Here is a example to show that `The assignment to m returned the value assigned.` in `awk` is incorrect.

```
$ awk 'function test() {a=2} BEGIN{print test()}'
<blank line>

$ perl -e 'sub test {$a=2}; print test'
2
```

You can see, what assignment return in `awk` example?

`awk 'n=(m=5);END{print n}' prints 5` because of *side effect*, it's not meaning `awk` assignment return value.

Comment: Michael Horner's statements are correct. In particular, the assignment to `m` does return the value assigned. Your example shows this — the value of `m=5` is 5, which is why 5 is assigned to `n` and later printed — so I don't understand what you're failing to understand.

Comment: @Gilles: What my example show? Do you see assignment in my awk test function return anything? Assignment is an expression, so it has its value. Its value is evaluated, not return.

Comment: If you want to be strict on terminology, the *expression* `m=5` is *evaluated*; it *evaluates to* the *value* 5, or to put it another way it *has* the *value* 5. The value is not evaluated. “Return” is usually used for function calls, but any programmer should understand “the expression returns 5” as “the expression evaluates to 5” even when the expression isn't a function call. At most, Michael's post used technically incorrect terminology, but yours is worse in this respect. The expression `m=5` has the same value as the expression `2+3`.

Comment: I understood Michael's answer without difficulty.  Don't know why you're thinking he's wrong.  And to be fair, his answer should be accepted.

Answer (score 10):

You have:

```
$NF=a[FNR]
```

as the final condition (the one that determines whether to print). Assignments return the value assigned, in this case `a[FNR]`. The first line of the data file from the linked question is:

```
A   0
```

`a[FNR]` is initialised to `$2`. That means the value of `a[FNR]` is `0`, which is a false value to awk. That means the assignment is false, which makes the conditional false and suppresses the default printing behaviour. If we change the data file to:

```
A   1
A   6   
B   0
```

then the first line will be printed, but the last one will be missing.

So it's not that the first line is absent, it's any line where the last field is zero (or empty). It just happens that the first line and only the first line was like that.

Comment: I think "Assignment return the value assigned" is not correct, see my own answer.

Comment: Try it: `awk 'm=n=0 ; END {print m}' file` prints a single `0`, because `n=0` returned `0`. As a condition that's false. Make it `2` and every line prints plus a `2` at the end.

Comment: No, as the doc said, nothing return from expression pattern in boolean context rather than **true** or **false**. "That means the assignment is false" is also wrong. Assignment alway success, whether you assign true or false value.

Comment: "The assignment is false" doesn't mean it fails to occur, it means it is treated as a false test result, which it is because the value is false. (This is also what your answer says, so I have no idea why you're arguing).

Comment: No, read my answer carefully. All thing I want to say, is that you think assignment return the value assigned is not correct.

Comment: Again: `awk 'n=(m=5);END{print n}'` prints `5`. *The assignment to m returned the value assigned*. Even `awk 'END{print (n=1),n}'` if you really want to see the result of assignment directly (it prints `1 1`). If you prefer, "an assignment expression in rvalue context evaluates to the value assigned". Any expression in boolean context is treated as false if it's `0` or `""` and true otherwise. This is exactly what I said and it's also what you said. **You said "the result of assignment is `0`", I said the return value of the assignment is `0`: these are totally synonymous statements**.

Comment: No, assignment to m not return the value assigned, Read: https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Assignment-Ops.html, expression has value, it does not return anything

Comment: See my updated answer!